# find and delete command deletes all files in that folder

Tags: linux, terminal

Currently, I am using this command to delete all files older than 30 minutes on my Linux server.

```
sudo find /var/www/html/folder/* -type f -mmin +30 -delete
```

But it deletes all the files in that folder irrespective of their age. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Add `-daystart` to the command

Comment: @0stone0 This doesn't help. All files are still being deleted.

Comment: Are you sure there are files that have been modified less than 30 minutes ago? Check with -30 and remove the delete

Comment: @RamanSailopal I created some news files just now and tested the command and it deleted them too. It clears the entire directory. I'll try with -30 now.

Comment: Works as designed here ... what file-system is this on, can you, instead of deleting, just for testing, do `-ls`?

Comment: @tink I'm on a tmpfs file system

Comment: Very odd ... can you please do the `-ls` instead of `-delete` with `find` and add that to your question?